# Disable Scrolling with JQUERY CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I search like an two hours for a solution but nothing worked.
Everytime they say `Overflow:Hidden` or `WIdth:100%`
but nothing off that works so i try my luck asking the question by myself

Comment: You will have to show some code...

Comment: what scrolling are you trying to disable?

Comment: since `overflow:hidden` disable-hide scrollbars how can you scroll?

Comment: @Sotiris Tab. If you focus an element it is scrolled into view, even if `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is it:

```
$('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

[**Living demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLHMy/)

Comment: @A.Wolff There was a typo. Try it again.

Comment: Isn't only `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');` needed?

Comment: ***INCORRECT*** [Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLHMy/1/). Focus the text box and press Tab. Ohey, you just scrolled the element!

Comment: Yes but for my case it works out its for a touch school infoboard and you dont have a keyboard to press tab
But yes thats a good point for other people who find this interesting.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what would you suggest instead.

Answer (score 1):

what about :

```
.noscroll{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
```

then add the class with jQuery to the body:

```
$('body').addClass('noscroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set overflow:hidden; to control? where scroll is appeared. Try to find it.